# render fields in form as pairs

Tags: python, django, forms

```
 <form action="/contact/" method="post">
 {% for field in form %}
 <div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
 </div>
{% endfor %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

the code works perfectly with a data entry per line, but in order to save space, i want to render the data in 2 sets per line..(i.e 2 fields per line and the use `<br>`)

it should look like

```
field1.tag : field1,   field2.tag: field2.
```

or some similar solution

Answer (score 1):

### Best solution: styling

The best solution is to solve it on styling level.

Like that ([see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xjmc8/)):

- template:

  ```
  <form action="/contact/" method="post">
      {% for field in form %}
          <div class="fieldWrapper">
              {{ field.errors }}
              {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
  </form>
  ```
- CSS:

  ```css
  .fieldWrapper {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
  }​
  ```

### Alternative solution: document structure

Alternatively you can use more complex template code to generate rows and columns. To do that, you can use [Django's `for` loop variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for), like:

- `forloop.counter` (or `forloop.counter0`) - containing number of the current element in the loop,
- `forloop.first` - `True` if current element is the first, `False` otherwise,
- `forloop.last` - `True` if current element is the last, `False` otherwise,

but presentation issues ("saving space on the screen") should be solved on styling layer.